# Error when trying to download file from Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have followed the docs on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrieveObjSingleOpPHP.html
to try and download a video.

This is my code below:

```
    $bucket = 'mybucketname';
    $keyname = 'AKIAJNCZ****************';

    // Instantiate the client.

    $s3 = S3Client::factory();

    try {
        // Get the object
        $result = $s3->getObject(array(
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key'    => $keyname
        ));

        // Display the object in the browser
        header("Content-Type: {$result['ContentType']}");
        echo $result['Body'];
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
```

The error message I get when going to the page is :

```
Missing required client configuration options: 

region: (string)

A "region" configuration value is required for the "s3" service
(e.g., "us-west-2"). A list of available public regions and endpoints can be
found at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html.

version: (string)

A "version" configuration value is required. Specifying a version constraint
ensures that your code will not be affected by a breaking change made to the
service. For example, when using Amazon S3, you can lock your API version to
"2006-03-01".

Your build of the SDK has the following version(s) of "s3": * "2006-03-01"

You may provide "latest" to the "version" configuration value to utilize the
most recent available API version that your client's API provider can find.
Note: Using 'latest' in a production application is not recommended.

A list of available API versions can be found on each client's API documentation
page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/index.html. If you are
unable to load a specific API version, then you may need to update your copy of
the SDK.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: storage::disk is not what the tutorial shows.

Comment: sorry , i have updated the question @tedder42, that was the error i get from $s3 = S3Client::factory();

Comment: Check this two articles http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/configuration.html https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/configuration.html

Comment: You need to set the region

Comment: I have set the region though

Comment: I dont see the region in the code`$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'region'  => 'us-east-1'
))`

Comment: Hi @Shibashis i have managed to do this now. But how can i let only logged in users have access to download the video, and stop just anyone from going directly to the url?

Comment: Logged in users to what? your app or aws account?